# JSON object is losing its value in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, error-handling

This error only comes up if I fail the validation the first time through.

If everything validates the first-time through, there is no error.

When the form passes, the controller performs this :

```
  respond_to do |wants|
    wants.json { render :json => { :html => (render_to_string :partial => 'disclaimer') } } 
  end
```

At this point, my `params[:order_of_importance] == 123` . Which is correct.

But once it gets brought to the beginning of the next action..

my `params[:order_of_importance] = HQ Number` . Where `HQ Number` is the `:value` of the text_field in my form.

Why would this be happening? What can I do to make sure the form holds the new information after it fails validation?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `params.freeze` then you should be able to see where the modification takes place since that will trigger an exception.

Comment: Wow interesting. Where/How would I call that exactly?

Comment: It'll prevent modification to that object, so call it just before you think the modification is occurring.